# Stuck on coding

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently working on a webproject.
I have to use a carousel Jquery, found that this looked the easiest to configure: http://ryrych.github.com/rcarousel/.

The site I'm working on: http://ripsraps.com/auzomapps/

The problem: When you press on the an app icon, I want the carousel to move to that page.
So basically what I'm asking; is there any way to make the links trigger the rotation, instead of those dots?

Comment: The demo seems to do exactly that.  What's the difference between your code and theirs?

Comment: some codes would like nicer in this post !!!

Comment: Check it out now. Can't get to hide the two dummy app pages properly. So if you have some suggestions, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean something like the goToPage command:

`$( "#carousel" ).rcarousel( "goToPage", 3 );`

So on your app icon try something like:

```
<a href="page.html" onclick="$('#carousel').rcarousel('goToPage', 3 ); return false;">
<img src="img/App-Random.png" width="65" height="88" border="0">
</a>
```

Where **3** is for example the number of the slide you are going to for the respective app icon.

NB: **page.html** should be some page to navigate to with appropriate information (maybe link it to the same image in the slide show), just in case JavaScript is not available and it is also better practice for search engine optimization. Optionally you can replace "page.html" with "#" if necessary.

More info at their online docs:

http://ryrych.github.com/rcarousel/#api

Comment: Thanks for tip!
Have tried some different things, aswell as added the "pages".
But they don't hide properly, aswell as they don't change when I press the icons. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think some close brackets are missing in your web page. At the bottom where the rcarousel function is called. Add the brackets right before the close script tag: <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(function($) { $( "#carousel" ).rcarousel( "goToPage", 1 ); });</script>

Comment: Tried that aswell. Still nothing.. :(

Comment: These things always turn out to be a challenge :) Did you try a simple implementation of the rcarousel? Just to make sure it works by default. This might highlight if a script file is missing, or if an HTML tag is out of place, etc. BTW, you may have to initialize the rcarousel before using it to specify a page. So add jQuery(function($) { $( "#carousel" ).rcarousel(); }); before using the other script.